# FullCalendar (jQuery) refetchEvent won't show events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I used to have

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //some properties...
    events: "/Agenda/GetEvents/",
});
```

It worked fine and my event showed correctly. Now I want to update the events (refetch) on a combobox selection, so here's what I changed:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //some properties...
    events: function (start, end) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Agenda/GetEvents/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),
                utilisateur: $("#Utilisateur option:selected").val()
            }
        });
        $('#Calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    },
});
```

The url at /Agenda/GetEvents/ gets called correctly and returns one event, but it won't show on the calendar anymore. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: refetchEvents works in every browser but IE for me.  I still haven't figured out how to make it work in IE.  Hope you get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was hard to find, but I found a workable way here

http://mikesmithdev.com/blog/jquery-full-calendar/

Comment: Yes, I was about to say that every time I have used 'refetchEvents' I had to remove the original events source, refetchEvents, and then add the new source (like I did in that post)... but then saw you found my solution... probably a little hard to copy since I was using two separate JSON feeds as sources in that. Consider also adding the code that you used to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation here to fetch events with single source.

[Full calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/)

Few changes are needed.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: function(start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myxmlfeed.php',
        dataType: 'xml',
        data: {
            // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
            start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
            end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
        },
        success: function(doc) {
            var events = [];
            $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                events.push({
                    title: $(this).attr('title'),
                    start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                });
            });
            callback(events);
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: I copypasted the 'success:' function, and it didn't change anything. The URL is called and returns JSON, but the events aren't displayed

Comment: Have you added the callback line as well?
**callback(events);**

Comment: Yes I did add that line too!

Comment: The loop '$(doc).find('event').each(function() {' contains nothing (and therefore never loops)

Comment: aah... i got that, it is an example i added. please check your object and place the name of your object there :)
You just have to iterate JSON correctly, and it will work fine..
If you can do this, then please paste the JSON object string which is returned from server :)

Comment: The above example is provided considering that you have an XML output which have <event> tags with information. please let me know what format you have.

Comment: Here's the JSON of my event: id = 2, title = 1, start = 1362060000, end = 1362067200, allDay = False

Answer (score 0):

After some hours reading the code, I found a unexpected configuration about allDay option. Each event must have allDay=false, like this:

```
evts.push({ title: "Teste", start: "2014/01/18 10:30", end: "2014/01/18 13:00", allDay: false });
callback(evts);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove callback function just call this from success block 
`$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');`